# Удалить N элементов, начиная с номера K, где N и K вводятся с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
 
 
int main(){
 
SetConsoleCP(65001);
SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
srand(time(NULL));
 
 
int size;
cout << "Enter size of array: ";
cin >> size;
 
int n;
int k;
cout << "Enter n: ";
cin >> n;
cout << "Enter k: ";
cin >> k;
 
 
 
 
int *arr = new int[size];
 
 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
 
 }
 cout << endl;
 
 
for (int k; k < size; k++)
{
 
       if (n > 0){
              n - 1;
              delete arr[k];
       }
       
}
 
 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
 
 }
 cout << endl;
 
 
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаление элементов в массиве производится не с помощью команды `delete[]`, а переписыванием данных с одного места на другое. Сначала до индекса **K** оставить всё в покое, а потом прописывать без удалённых **N** элементов

```
arr[0]        = arr[0]
..
arr[k-1]      = arr[k-1]
arr[k]        = arr[k+n]
..
arr[size-1-n] = arr[size-1]
arr[size-n]   = XXX
...
```

Дальше надо не забывать уменьшить переменную `size`, так как вы удалили эти элементы. Только в конце программы уже можно один раз освободить выделенную память у системы с помощью `delete[]`.

В своей попытке вы **заново** определили переменную `k`, `for (int k; k < size; k++)` и она объявляется новой и скрывает начальную переменную. Повторное определение обычно всегда приводит к логическим ошибкам.

Вот так происходит перемещение данных :

```
for ( int j = k ; j < size-n; ++j )
   arr [j] = arr [j+n];
size -= n ;
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ!!! Все работает, только можете пожалуйста объяснить почему size -= n идет после цикла, и почему в цикле ++j, а не j++

Comment: всё дело привычки и вкуса, например: `*(a+i) == a[i]` Размер уменьшаю после выполненной работы. можно и перед этим, и тогда будет чуток цикл быстрее работать. `++j` - понятнее: увеличить переменную, и её значение вернуть.  `j++` возвращает старое значение переменной и **после** всех вычислений в строке увеличивает её значение. Это имеет разницу, если вы потом это значение куда-нибудь будете присваивать.

Comment: Если я уменьшу размер перед переносом, то придётся заново рисовать таблицу, что откуда и куда присваивать. Так как `size` - это **не** размер массива, а количество данных **будет в новом** массиве. Можно легко заблудиться и наделать ошибок.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за ваш ответ! Вы мне очень помогли, сейчас хочу переделать с функциями, но  что то оно не выводит правильно, может если будет время у вас и желание, посмотрите, может я что-то не то в функцию передаю. Я сейчас обновлю вопрос.

Comment: А все, я все сделал, спасибо вам еще раз!